# How to use footer in Matrix?

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, footer, ssrs-2012

I am trying to design a one page matrix with common header and footer. The header and footer size should be equal to matrix size. Since matrix column is dynamic I am not able to fix the footer size, for 1st row cell merging option was available so i am using that for header, but there is no cell merging option in the last row of matrix for footer.

Is there any possible solution for footer?

Please refer the attach image. In 2nd image footer is repeating but I am trying to design like 1st Image.

[image]

Comment: Why not using textboxes outside the matrix?

Comment: It seems this behaviour is by design, values are repeated even on the footer of matrix when they are positioned inside the dynamic parts of the matrix (student grouping). Also the merge button is disabled if your selection is a mix of static and dynamic textboxes.

Comment: The only workaround I can think of would be to make a separate table for the footer. Have it grouped the same way, but make the details row invisible. Then put the "footer" text in the column header area. This way, the width will grow at the same rate as the 1st table, but you still have the option to merge the cells.